# How to deserialize JSON to .NET object using JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JSON object like the following

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "18128270850211_49239570772655",
         "from": {
            "name": "Someone Unimportant",
            "id": "57583427"
         }
         /* more stuff */
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to parse it using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx),

```
FacebookResponse<FacebookPost> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookResponse<FacebookPost>>(json);

internal class FacebookResponse<T> where T : class
{
    public IList<T> Data { get; set; }
    public FacebookResponsePaging Paging { get; set; }
}

public class FacebookPost
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("to.data.id")]
    public string FeedId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("from.id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_time")]
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updated_time")]
    public DateTime UpdatedTime { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; } // TODO: Type enum??

    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Everything comes through except for the `FeedId` and the `UserId` properties. How should I be mapping these?

Comment: You need to define a "from" class to match the json data. Same thing for "to" (if it differs from "from" in structure) and "data"

Comment: If you don't like having a lot of classes around you can use structs as well.  I prefer them because they are _just_ data like the JSON.

Comment: How about `dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); var name = obj.data[0].from.name;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [site](http://json2csharp.com/) to get the object for .net

Then you can use JSON.Net to deserialize: ex.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input) iirc

Comment: can't I do this directly? I was more interested in an attribute-based approach using JSON.NET features

Answer (score 1):

```
public class From
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
}

public class FacebookPost
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

internal class FacebookResponse<T> where T : class
{
    public IList<T> Data { get; set; }
    public FacebookResponsePaging Paging { get; set; }
}

FacebookResponse<FacebookPost> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookResponse<FacebookPost>>(json);
```

Try below code :)